# MSSQL Query - database

Tags: sql-server

I need help in a query to get me result as below based on this table.

```
Table
ID   Date Value
---  ---- -----
1    jan1  Hello
2    Jan2  Sample
```

Query Result:

```
ID   Date Value  Info
---  ---- -----  -----
1    jan1  Hello  A
1    jan1  Hello  B
2    Jan2  Sample A
2    Jan2  Sample B
```

Can any help me please?

Comment: Where does that Info come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` here, with a computed column for `Info`:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Value, 'A' AS Info
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Date, Value, 'B'
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the info column to be based on the values of another column, use case.

[MSDN case documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)